# In Kubernetes, usage of Cluster IP can replace the usage of Pod IP?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, microservices, nat

In K8S, there are cluster IP and pod IP and I understand the difference between two.

I have two questions.

1. Usage of Cluster IP can replace usage of Pod IP?
   The cluster IP is used for the networking between the servers in the same cluster. Pod IP is also for the internal network traffic. In our company's legacy service, the pod IP is used so it needs a server which manage the pod IP of every server. We are making the new service now. When connecting the service mesh in Micro Service Architecture (MSA) server which is scalable (by duplication of pods), can I use the cluster IP? If so, why the service mesh tools like ISTIO and Spring Cloud Eureka is required in MSA? The cluster IP can be used instead of these tools.
2. Why the pod IP is designed to be changed when the pod is recreated?

Comment: Attaching supporting [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/) for refernece.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Kubernetes, it installs a private network which are used by the pods.

This is a class like 10.0.0.0/24 . So your node in this case have 256 ipaddresses available to run your pods.

Those Ipaddresses are not accessible from outside your node directly.

Each time a Pod starts one of the available Ipaddresses is assigned to the pod. Thats also the so called clusterIP.

Normally you have more than one node. So on each node there is configured such a network for the Pods.

To communicate between the pods clusterIps on different nodes a Network Fabric must be installed in the cluster. (ex. Flannel or Calico).

The Pods clusterIp you cant predict. It can change every time a Pod is recreated. To connect Pods between them create a service with type: ClusterIP.

Unless you do like so: (FROM Kubernetes documentation)

*You can specify your own cluster IP address as part of a Service creation request. To do this, set the .spec.clusterIP field. For example, if you already have an existing DNS entry that you wish to reuse, or legacy systems that are configured for a specific IP address and difficult to re-configure.
The IP address that you choose must be a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address from within the service-cluster-ip-range CIDR range that is configured for the API server. If you try to create a Service with an invalid clusterIP address value, the API server will return a 422 HTTP status code to indicate that there's a problem.*

But thats let you run in the issue if the choosen IP-addresse is already in use.

Kubernetes has an internal DNS.
You can access a pod like so:

```
servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local:port
```